# Streamlit does not showing a map and there's no trouble

Tags: python, numpy, github, streamlit, geemap

I'm working on estimation chlorophyll-a using a Landsat 8 image and then I’m trying to build an web-app which is using streamlit and geemap library. But my map doesn’t showing in the web-app. When I ran it from [share streamlit](https://share.streamlit.io/), everything seemed to work just fine and there is no traceback. My script that didn’t showing the map is on the

```
import ee
import geemap
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np

def L8_T1():
    
    st.header("Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 1")
    
    row1_col1, row1_col2 = st.columns([3, 1])
    width = 950
    height = 600
    
    m = geemap.Map()

    start_year = 2013
    end_year = 2020
    study_area = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
        [121.731876,-2.330221], [121.069735, -2.317823], [121.214026,-2.994612],[121.785511,-2.992766]
    ])

    collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR') \
        .filterBounds(study_area)

    yearlist = range(start_year, end_year)


    def mask_clouds(image):
        # Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
        cloud_shadow_bit_mask = (1 << 3)
        clouds_bit_mask = (1 << 5)
        # Get the pixel QA band.
        qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
        # Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
        mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud_shadow_bit_mask).eq(0) \
            .And(qa.bitwiseAnd(clouds_bit_mask).eq(0))
        return image \
            .divide(10000) \
            .divide(3.141593) \
            .updateMask(mask)


    def calculate_clorophil_a(year) :
        image = collection \
            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')) \
            .map(mask_clouds) \
            .median()
        ndwi = image \
            .normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']) \
            .rename('NDWI')
        clorophil_a = image \
            .expression('10**(-0.9889*((RrsB4)/(RrsB5))+0.3619)', {
                'RrsB4': image.select('B4'),
                'RrsB5': image.select('B5')
            }) \
            .updateMask(ndwi)
        return clorophil_a \
            .set('year', year) \
            .set('month', 1) \
            .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1,1)) \
            .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1))

    clorophil_a_collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
        calculate_clorophil_a(year)
        for year in yearlist
    ])
    print(clorophil_a_collection.getInfo())

    parameter = {'min':0, 'max':1, 'palette':['blue','green']}

    #m.addLayer(clorophil_a_collection,parameter,"Clorophyll-a")
    #m.setControlVisibility(layerControl=True, fullscreenControl=True, latLngPopup=True)
    #m.add_colorbar(
    #parameter,
    #label="Clorophyll-a (mg/m3)",
    #orientation="horizontal",
    #layer_name="Clorophyll-a",
    #transparent_bg=True,
    #)
    #m.to_streamlit(width=width, height=height)
    
    years1 = ["2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]
    
    with row1_col2:
        selected_year = st.multiselect("Select a year", years1)
        add_chart = st.checkbox("Show chart")

    if selected_year:
        for year in selected_year:
            Map.addLayer(calculate_clorophil_a(year), parameter, "Clorophyll-a " + year)

        if add_chart:
            Map.add_legend(
                legend_title="Clorophyll-a (mg/m3)", builtin_legend="NLCD"
            )
        with row1_col1:
            Map.to_streamlit(width=width, height=height)

    else:
        with row1_col1:
            Map.to_streamlit(width=width, height=height)

def L8_T2():
    
    st.header("Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 2")
    
    row1_col1, row1_col2 = st.columns([3, 1])
    width = 950
    height = 600
    
    m = geemap.Map()

    start_year = 2016
    end_year = 2020
    study_area = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
        [121.731876,-2.330221], [121.069735, -2.317823], [121.214026,-2.994612], [121.785511,-2.992766]
    ])

    collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR') \
                .filterBounds(study_area)

    yearlist = range(start_year, end_year)


    def mask_clouds(image):
        # Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
        cloud_shadow_bit_mask = (1 << 20)
        clouds_bit_mask = (1 << 25)
        # Get the pixel QA band.
        qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
        # Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
        mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud_shadow_bit_mask).eq(0) \
            .And(qa.bitwiseAnd(clouds_bit_mask).eq(0))
        return image\
            .divide(10000)\
            .divide(3.141593)\
            .updateMask(mask)

    #coba diganti pi

    def calculate_clorophil_a(year) :
        image = collection \
            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')) \
            .map(mask_clouds) \
            .median() 
        ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI')
        clorophil_a = image.expression(
            '10**(-0.9889*((RrsB4)/(RrsB5))+0.3619)', {
                'RrsB4': image.select('B4'),
                'RrsB5': image.select('B5')
            }).updateMask(ndwi)
        return clorophil_a \
            .set('year', year) \
            .set('month', 1) \
            .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1,1)) \
            .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1))

    clorophil_a_collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
        calculate_clorophil_a(year)
        for year in yearlist
    ])
    print(clorophil_a_collection.getInfo())

    parameter = {'min':0, 'max':1, 'palette':['blue','green']}

    #m.addLayer(clorophil_a_collection,parameter,"Clorophyll-a")
    #m.setControlVisibility(layerControl=True, fullscreenControl=True, latLngPopup=True)
    #m.add_colorbar(
    #parameter,
    #label="Clorophyll-a (mg/m3)",
    #orientation="horizontal",
    #layer_name="Clorophyll-a",
    #transparent_bg=True,
    #)
    #m.to_streamlit(width=width, height=height)
    
    years2 = ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]
    
    with row1_col2:
        selected_year = st.multiselect("Select a year", years2)
        add_chart = st.checkbox("Show chart")

    if selected_year:
        for year in selected_year:
            Map.addLayer(calculate_clorophil_a(year), parameter, "Clorophyll-a " + year)

        if add_chart:
            Map.add_legend(
                legend_title="Clorophyll-a (mg/m3)", builtin_legend="NLCD"
            )
        with row1_col1:
            Map.to_streamlit(width=width, height=height)

    else:
        with row1_col1:
            Map.to_streamlit(width=width, height=height)            
    
def app():
    st.title("Chlorophyll-a")

    st.markdown("""

    Aplikasi Web ini dibuat dengan menggunakan Streamlit untuk menampilkan nilai 
    estimasi besar klorofil-a pada Danau Matano dan Danau Towuti menggunakan 
    algoritma Jaelani 2015 berdasarkan jurnal [Pemetaan Distribusi Spasial Konsentrasi Klorofil-A dengan Landsat 8 di Danau Matano dan Danau Towuti, Sulawesi Selatan](http://lipi.go.id/publikasi/pemetaan-distribusi-spasial-konsentrasi-klorofil-a-dengan-landsat-8-di-danau-matano-dan-danau-towuti-sulawesi-selatan/2062)

    """)
    
    apps = ["Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 1", "Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 2"]
    
    selected_app = st.selectbox("Select an app", apps)
    
    if selected_app == "Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 1":
        L8_T1()
    elif selected_app == "Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 2":
        L8_T2()
```

And then these are all my script : [GitHubAji](https://github.com/martantiaji/chlplandsat8)
Any advice for this trouble?

Comment: Can you see the map if you don't use streamlit?

Comment: yes, i can see the map when i ran it on the local computer